# Automatization for automatization

Tags: plugins, multisite, blog

I have a wordpress multisite for a bunch of friends of mine.
And every time I create a new blog there are a few things I have to do before I can give it to them.

- Activate a new plugin
- Create a new page with a specific title

I am wondering if there is and kind of script i can record to make this happen. 
I.e. in MS Office there is a way to record makros which will record what you do and then repeat it.

Is there something similar in wordpress?

Answer (score 0):

WordPress has no macros like that but it can be done.

If the plugin is already installed, you can [Network Activate](http://codex.wordpress.org/Multisite_Network_Administration#Plugins) it so it will be available on any blog in the network.

As for the page with title, you'll need to create or source a plugin to do that as it will need to be created after the site is created.

A quick and untested approach:

```
add_action( 'wpmu_new_blog', 'wpse_190815');

function wpse_190815( $blog_id ) {
    $page_title = 'Custom Page Title';

    $post_data = array(
        'post_type'  => 'page',
        'post_title' => $page_title,
    );

    //switch to the new blog
    switch_to_blog( $blog_id );

    //create the new page
    $page = wp_insert_post( $post_data );

    //go back to the current blog
    restore_current_blog();

}
```

This should probably go in [wp-content/mu-plugins](https://codex.wordpress.org/Must_Use_Plugins) to be sure it's always loaded.

Hope this helps!